# How to get hibernate mapping files from another project using xml based config?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm working with spring and hibernate. Currently I have the context config file like this

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">

    <!-- other properties -->

    <property name="mappingDirectoryLocations" value="classpath:mappings/" />     
</bean>
```

the `*.hbm.xml` mappings are in the same project.

Now I plan to pull some entities together with the mappings out, so they can be shared with other projects. The question is, how should I configure the `sessionFactory` bean to get `*.hbm.xml` files from the newly created project?
I tried `mappingJarLocations` but got error saying that the class path is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `classpath:` use `classpath*:`.

Check [What is the difference between "classpath:" and "classpath:/" in Spring XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994840/what-is-the-difference-between-classpath-and-classpath-in-spring-xml) for a extended answer on the differences between the 2.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but got FileNotFoundException: `URL [jar:file:path/to/jar/foo.jar!/mappings/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:path/to/jar/foo.jar!/mappings/`

Comment: Try the `mappingLocation` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

AFASIK, Hibernate looks for mentioned hbm files in all the jars in classpath. You need to mention only the files.

Comment: Do you mean using `mappingLocations` and list all the files?