# Query on Spring property-placeholder

Tags: spring

What is the difference between the following two:

```
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties"/>

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:*.properties"/>
```

The syntax difference is too small: in the first there is an extra '*' after the classpath.

Btw, I am using Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE

Comment: [maybe will help](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13994840/2587435)